# Google wallet NFC pass

Tags: android, google-wallet

Im having trouble adding NFC pass to Google wallet. I have successfully added normal pass with QR code but when wanting to enable `smartTap` it wont work. I have enabled smartTap in google wallet console.

When im adding the NFC pass, it shows icon of NFC that it is a NFC card, but when selecting it in google wallet for use, its not showing NFC indicator for scanning.

```
let genericObject = {
    id: `${objectId}`,
    classId: `${issuerId}.${classSuffix}`,
    genericType: "GENERIC_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
    hexBackgroundColor: "#4285f4",
    logo: {
        sourceUri: {
            uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/pass_google_logo.jpg",
        },
    },
    cardTitle: {
        defaultValue: {
            language: "en-US",
            value: "test Card",
        },
    },
    subheader: {
        defaultValue: {
            language: "en-US",
            value: "EMPLOYEE",
        },
    },
    header: {
        defaultValue: {
            language: "en-US",
            value: "Pero Peric",
        },
    },
    barcode: {
        type: "QR_CODE",
        value: `${objectId}`,
    },
    smartTapRedemptionValue: "test",
    heroImage: {
        sourceUri: {
            uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/google-io-hero-demo-only.jpg",
        },
    },
    textModulesData: [
        {
            header: "COMPANY",
            body: "test plus d.o.o.",
            id: "points",
        },
        {
            header: "JOB TITLE",
            body: "Head of department",
            id: "contacts",
        },
    ],
};
```

[pass when adding to Wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VRsp.jpg)

[pass when selected from wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkg97.jpg)

Im adding pass via JWTToken from android app:

```
  walletClient.savePassesJwt(token, this, addToGoogleWalletRequestCode)
```

I want to add NFC capability to generic pass

Comment: Do you have `enableSmartTap` set to true, as well as `redemptionIssuers` on the GenericClass JSON? If not, this could be an issue. We show a small example in the “Putting your issuer ID in your Google pass JWT payload” section here: https://passninja.com/tutorials/google-platform/how-to-generate-ids-for-google-nfc-passes

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. The only thing you need to do is through console is:

- Copy your "Issuer Id" from the Wallet Api Console
- Open the Class Object you want to update
- Edit the "Redemption Issuer"
- Add your "Issuer Id" and save

Comment: I have added my issuerId as a redemption Issuer of class like u said but still no luck. :/
Could it be a problem in my pass object? Maybe genericType: `GENERIC_PASS_TYPE`?

Comment: No, it does not matter which type it is. It works with the steps i have mentioned above